# reRender not working on a pageBlockTable column with actionSupport and actionRegion

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, salesforce-classic

I have an `actionSupport` with `actionReqion` on `pageBlockTable` which is not rendering  properly but it renders perfectly on `pageBlockSectionItem`.

```
        <apex:pageblocktable>
             <apex:column style="width:50px" rendered="{!vehicleOrder}">
                  <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Car" for="selectedcar"/>
                  </apex:facet> 
                       <apex:actionRegion >
                        <apex:selectList value="{!vw.Item.Car__c}" size="1" id="selectedcar">  
                          <apex:actionSupport event="onChange"  rerender="models" immediate="true"/>
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!vw.carOptions}">
                           </apex:selectOptions>
                        </apex:selectList>
                      </apex:actionRegion>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column style="width:50px" rendered="{!vehicleOrder}">
                   <apex:facet name="header">
                     <apex:outputLabel value="Model" for="models"/>
                   </apex:facet>            
                    <apex:actionRegion >
                     <apex:selectList value="{!vw.Item.Model__c}" size="1" id="models" disabled="{!ISNULL(selectedcar)}"> 
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!vw.modelOptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
                     </apex:selectList> 
                   </apex:actionRegion> 
                </apex:column> 
          </apex:pageblocktable>
```

Comment: in what context? lex, classic? what part is not rendering (the whole pageblocktable)? any errors?

Comment: Its classic, on "Car" selection the "Model" list should render. There are no specific errors just the rendering of model list column is not working

Comment: I believe this has to do with how Visualforce resolves component Ids. If you give the whole `<apex:pageBlockTable>` an Id and rerender it, does that work?

Comment: Are you hoping that in a given row of your table, the select options will change just in that row based on the items selected in an adjacent column?

Comment: Yes, the models should change based on car selection on same row

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you may need to address. (And let me confess, this is completely from memory for how this feature works!)

From what I can tell the conditional (with the `rendered` attribute) for that block of markup is the column, but you're only rerendering a node that is inside that column, which is a non-rendered node.

```
     this part is not rendered--------------V
                                            V
<apex:column style="width:50px" rendered="{!vehicleOrder}">
   <apex:facet name="header">

but this is what you're rerendering---------V
                                            V
     <apex:outputLabel value="Model" for="models"/>
   </apex:facet>            
    <apex:actionRegion >
     <apex:selectList value="{!vw.Item.Model__c}" size="1" id="models" disabled="{!ISNULL(selectedcar)}"> 
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!vw.modelOptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
     </apex:selectList> 
   </apex:actionRegion> 
</apex:column>
```

Rerendering something that isn't rendered in the first place will always fail. Even attempting to rerender the node directly, your `apex:outputLabel` in this example, will fail. You always need to rerender something one level or more higher than the thing you want to make appear/disappear. In this instance, it looks like that should be your `apex:pageBlockTable` element.

The other thing that is likely impeding progress is `immediate="true"` in your `apex:actionSupport` tag.

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onChange" rerender="models" immediate="true"/>
```

By setting this, you will not post back any data from your current page state. Presumably you'd need to do that to toggle the `vehicleOrder` property and thus make the column appear when your table rerenders.

Comment: Removed the rendered attribute on column and tried to render the entire pageblock table but still the rendering is not happening